What methods can quickly determine the coefficient of determination of the data?
The given data is:
x = {0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.05, 0.05, 0.07, 0.07, 0.06};
y = {0.25, 0.4, 0.22, 0.54, 0.51, 0.34, 0.36, 0.46, 0.42, 0.4};

Is there a quicker method to calculate the coefficient of determination for this dataset? The approach I used involved step-by-step computation using the formula for the coefficient of determination.

x = {0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.08, 0.08, 0.05, 0.05, 0.07, 0.07, 0.06};
y = {0.25, 0.4, 0.22, 0.54, 0.51, 0.34, 0.36, 0.46, 0.42, 0.4};
data = Thread@{x, y};
meanY = Mean[y];
SST = Total[(y - meanY)^2];
lm = LinearModelFit[data, t, t]
residuals = lm["FitResiduals"]
SSE = Total[residuals^2]
rSquared = 1 - SSE/SST


lm["RSquared"] ?

For a simple linear model (just one predictor) try Correlation[x, y]^2.  For linear models with more than one predictor use @ydd 's suggestion.

What is a "coefficient of determination"?

@DavidG.Stork Please see the content introduction in this web address:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination

Thanks.  I have always referred to it as $R^2$.

https://i.sstatic.net/ASlLOO8J.png https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/106028/1871 (-1)

If you want to be "old school" (using linear algebra):
a = Thread[{1, x}];
sol = Inverse[Transpose[a] . a] . Transpose[a] . y
Plot[Inverse[Transpose[a] . a] . Transpose[a] . y . {1, t}, {t, 0.03, 
  0.08}, Epilog -> Point[Thread[{x, y}]], PlotRange -> All]


Using LinearModelFit and comparing with linear algebra:
lm = LinearModelFit[Thread[{x, y}], {1, s}, s];
lm["RSquared"]
d = y - Mean[y];
vec = a . sol - y;
1 - vec . vec/d . d

->
0.947046
0.947046

Does using PseudoInverse count as old school? Or intermediate-oldish school?

Yes you are right. This simple example… I was just sadly amusing myself
